# tidyverse: splitting string to data.frame as rows

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, stringr

I want to split a string based on `\n` into rows of a `data.frame`. Code is given below which is not working as required. Any hint.

```
library(tidyverse)
Test <- "ASD 7\nDEF \n This"

library(stringr)
str_split(string = Test, pattern = "\n")
[[1]]
[1] "ASD 7" "DEF "  " This
    
tb <- 
  as_tibble(Test) %>% 
  set_names("Test")

tb %>% 
  str_split(string = Test, pattern = "\n")
[[1]]
[1] NA

Warning message:
In stri_split_regex(string, pattern, n = n, simplify = simplify,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

**Required Output**

```
ASD 7
DEF
This
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_split` is designed to work on atomic vectors and not on datasets.  It has no argument as `data` therefore it will work only like this

```
str_split(tb$Test, '\n')

[[1]]
[1] "ASD 7" "DEF "  " This"
```

OR

```
> tb %>%
+   mutate(chr_list = str_split(Test, '\n'))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Test                 chr_list 
  <chr>                <list>   
1 "ASD 7\nDEF \n This" <chr [3]>
```

Moreover, if you like to do it in database, you may do `tidyr::separate` or `tidyr::separate_rows()` like this

```
tb %>%
  separate_rows(Test, sep = '\n')

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Test   
  <chr>  
1 "ASD 7"
2 "DEF " 
3 " This"
```

OR

```
tb %>%
  separate(Test, into = c('A', 'B', 'C'), sep = '\n')

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  A     B      C      
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  
1 ASD 7 "DEF " " This"
```

---

PS:  If you want to remove white spaces too, you may use `'\\s*\n+\\s*'` as separating pattern

```
tb %>%
  transmute(text_data = map(str_split(Test, '\n'), ~ str_trim(.x))) %>%
  unnest_longer(text_data)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  text_data
  <chr>    
1 ASD 7    
2 DEF      
3 This
```

OR

```
tb %>%
  separate_rows(Test, sep = "\\s*\n+\\s*")

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Test 
  <chr>
1 ASD 7
2 DEF  
3 This
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. My bad. Please see updates.